# infopath 2010 person and group retrieve email

Tags: infopath

i want to make the code send email that is picked from active directory inside a text box

```
XPathNavigator dataSource;
dataSource = this.MainDataSource.CreateNavigator();
string toAddress = dataSource.SelectSingleNode
("/my:myFields/my:toAddress/pc:Person/pc:AccountId",NamespaceManager).Value;
dataSource.SelectSingleNode("//my:field1",NamespaceManager).SetValue(this.User.UserName);
```

so how can i retrieve person and group email and put it inside a text box and which one of this i should use (account id or account type, display name ).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the AccountId property - depending on your AuthenticationProvider it's either the user's email or the domain account. If it's the domain acccount, it might still work because IIS can resolve it automatically.

If it doesn't work with the AccountId you have to query the GetUserProfileByName WebService and retrieve all properties (incl. email). [Here](http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/userprofileservice-extended/) is an excellent article how to do this without writing code.